# Issue with WSO2 ESB Proxy Service and JMS Queue Name

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB the consumer proxy service is not picking up the messages from the queue when queue name is different from service name. It works fine when service name and queue name is same.
For example it works when:

**Queue Name**: Organisation.01.GetOrganisation.001

**Service Name**: Organisation.01.GetOrganisation. 001

But not working when:

**Queue Name:** ES.Organisation.01.Request.GetOrganisation.001.

**Service Name**: Organisation. 01.GetOrganisation. 001

Please i need help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omer recently I have also faced same issue in WSO2 ESB. The Solution for this problem is, you have to pass the parameters to your ESB proxy service.

These are the parameters:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
     <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">YourQueueName</parameter>
     <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
```

For more information, you can refer to this link.
[WSO2 official blog](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker/)